# How to get the below pandas output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I achieve this with pandas

```
inputindex  |country_id|country_name|  value | desc
1            2                 JAV       3         a
2            3                 GBR       7         b
3            4                 GBR       5         e
4            7                  BDI      6         r
```

output

```
index | country_id|country_name| value| desc
1              2       JAV       3       a
2              3       GBR       12     b,e
4              7       BDI       6       r
```

Comment: simple `groupby`+`agg` with `sum` and `list` or `str.join`

Comment: @mozway - and `first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with 3 different functions - [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), `sum` and `join`:

```
df = (df.groupby('country_name', as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg(country_id = ('country_id', 'first'),
             value = ('value','sum'),
             desc = ('desc', ','.join)))
print (df)
  country_name  country_id  value desc
0          JAV           2      3    a
1          GBR           3     12  b,e
2          BDI           7      6    r
```